# SwiftUI - Animating HUD / Pop Over like iOS Silent Mode

Tags: animation, swiftui, popover, hud

I'm trying to clone the following animation from iOS:

[image]

Here's my code. I'm stuck with the animation of the star. I'd for example like to shake it a little bit or rotate it around it's y-axis.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PopOver(image: "star.fill", color: .primary, title: "Thank You!")
    }
}

struct PopOver: View{
    
    var image: String
    var color: Color
    var title: String

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
    
    var body: some View{
        
        HStack(spacing: 10){
            
            Image(systemName: image)
                .font(.title3)
                .foregroundColor(color)
            
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
        .padding(.vertical,10)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(
            scheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white
        )
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 1, y: 5)
        .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.03), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        .offset(y: 0)
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how this can be achieved?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popUpPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {popUpPresented = true}) {
            Text("click me")
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $popUpPresented, arrowEdge: .top) {
            PopOver(image: "star.fill", color: .primary, title: "Thank You!")
        }
    }
}

struct PopOver: View{
    var image: String
    var color: Color
    var title: String

    @State var rotate = 0.0  // <-- here
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack(spacing: 10){
            Image(systemName: image).font(.title3).foregroundColor(color)
                // --- here ---
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle.degrees(rotate), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                .task {
                    withAnimation(Animation.default.speed(0.3).delay(0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)){
                        rotate = 360.0
                    }
                }
            Text(title).foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
        .padding(.vertical,10)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(scheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 1, y: 5)
        .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.03), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        .offset(y: 0)
    }
}
```